# Formulation of Random Variable Equation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, random-variables, binomial-distribution

So I have a discrete distribution:$$Pr[X=k]=p B(n, a) + (1-p) B(n, b)$$
where $B(n, a)$ and $B(n, b)$ are binomial distributions. I wrote this mixture of distributions from two populations like this:

Let $X\sim B(n, a)$ and let $Y \sim B(n, b)\\$. Then:$$Z \sim p X+(1-p)Y$$
Where Z is my original discrete random variable. Is this notation correct?

Comment: The second yes, but the first no... $\text{Bin}(n,a)$ is not a number

Comment: So the first one and: $$ Pr(X=k)  =  p \binom{n}{k} \cdot a^k(1-a)^{n-k} + (1-p) \binom{n}{k} \cdot b^k(1-b)^{n-k}$$ are not the same?

Comment: No. First you have to know if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not. In the case that they are, you have to calculate the distribution of $pX+(1-p)Y$

Comment: The first statement should read $$Pr[X=k]=p B(n, a)(k) + (1-p) B(n, b)(k)$$ for every $k$. Its translation in terms of random variables that you suggest is wrong since your $pX+(1-p)Y$ is not always an integer although your $Z$ is. A correct translation is to choose $Y\sim B(n,a)$, $Z\sim B(n,b)$, independent or not, in addition to choose some $B\sim Ber(p)$ independent of $(Y,Z)$, and then to declare that $$X=BY+(1-B)Z$$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Sorry but your second comment is sending the OP in an incorrect direction.

Comment: @Did I assumed that p is fixed. The problem is that they are two different models (yours and mine). We have to see what Dylan Zammit really needs

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo That $p$ is fixed is (true and) irrelevant. Again, $X$ is integer valued hence what you call your model is absurd.

Comment: @Did You said that "$pX+(1−p)Y$  is not always an integer". Why is that?

Comment: ?? Because $X$ and $Y$ are integers and $p$ can be any real number between $0$ and $1$, say $p=\pi/4$...

Comment: oh right, my bad :) stupid question. Now I'm embarrassed. Thanks for the help